# How To Update Ui Incomming App In Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i develop a android app with flutter.
   Is it possible to change the Ui of the phone's call app?
For example, a button can be added on the input call page where we can reject the call or answer the call.

[image: Like the picture below]

Comment: Not on iOS.  Apps can't change the behaviour of in-built device functionality.

Comment: Ok Thankyou.on android can change ?